# Is Bioshift affected by Doubling Season?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I just want to know if [Bioshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bioshift) is affected by [Doubling Season](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doubling%20Season). The text states that [Bioshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bioshift) moves counters from a target to another, but is that the same as "putting them on" a target?

Comment: Actually, I made a deck last year that was based on this.

Comment: I am working on a Hydra Deck at the moment, where bioshift is going to play a vital part, after I had this issue clarified!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it does. See the rulings on [Bioshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bioshift):

> To move a counter from one creature to another, the counter is removed from the first creature and placed on the second. **Any abilities that care about a counter being removed or placed on a creature will apply.**

The ruling stems from the following rule:

> 121.5. If an effect says to “move” a counter, it means to take that counter from the object it’s currently on and put it onto a second object. If the first and second objects are the same object, nothing happens. If the first object has no counters, nothing happens; the second object doesn’t get a counter put on it. If the second object (or any possible second objects) is no longer in the correct zone when the effect would move the counter, nothing happens; a counter isn’t removed from the first object.